Are there any religious texts that depict Lord Shiva as a female deity with Parvati as his consort?
One quora post here asks a question "Are there any religious texts that depict Lord Shiva as a female deity with Parvati as his consort?" For which answer is also give without quoting any verse. below is the answer:
"In Mahabhagwat upapurana, in one of the kalpa (most probably saraswat kalpa), it is mentioned that Shiva took female form as radha and parvati took male form as Krishna and incarnated on earth. Don't confuse with radha krishna of current kalpa (shwetavaraha kalpa) who are Lakshmi and Narayana. In Sarasvata kalpa, Shiva and Shakti took the incarnation of Radha and Krishna."
if you can provide link and proof of Lord Shiva taking form of radha and Maa Parvati taking form of Lord Krishna would be helpful. also, if you know the details of this then please post the link or the complete story of the same.
